# How to find all kendo ui grid names using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have multiple grids in my page. I want to select  of grids using jquery. How can I select them?

```
$("how find grids?").each(function (index, element) {
       if (element) {
          
           console.log("element: " + element);
          
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('div[data-role="grid"]')
```

or

```
$('div.k-grid')
```